# Bulk inject doc to elastic search with nanoseconds timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the latest nanoseconds support provided by ElasticSearch 7.1 (Actually after 7.0). Not sure how to do this correctly.

Before 7.0, ElasticSearch only support timestamp for milliseconds, I use the _bulk API to inject documents.

```py
#bulk post docs to elastic search
def es_bulk_insert(log_lines, batch_size=1000):
   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson'}
   while log_lines:
       batch, log_lines = log_lines[:batch_size], log_lines[batch_size:]
       batch = '\n'.join([x.es_post_payload for x in batch]) + '\n'
       request = AWSRequest(method='POST', url=f'{ES_HOST}/_bulk', data=batch, headers=headers)
       SigV4Auth(boto3.Session().get_credentials(), 'es', 'eu-west-1').add_auth(request)
       session = URLLib3Session()
       r = session.send(request.prepare())
       if r.status_code > 299:
           raise Exception(f'Received a bad response from Elasticsearch: {r.text}')
```

The log index is generated per day

```py
#ex:
#log-20190804
#log-20190805
def es_index(self):
       current_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')
       return f'{self.name}-{current_date}'
```

The timestamp is in nanoseconds "2019-08-07T23:59:01.193379911Z" and it's automatically mapping to a date type by Elasticsearch before 7.0.

```
"timestamp": {
    "type": "date"
},
```

Now I want to map the timestamp field to the "date_nanos" type. From [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date_nanos.html), I think I need to create the ES index with correct mapping before I call the es_bulk_insert() function to upload docs.

```
GET https://{es_url}/log-20190823
If not exist (return 404)
PUT https://{es_url}/log-20190823/_mapping
{
 "properties": {
    "timestamp": {
      "type": "date_nanos" 
    }
  }
}
...
call es_bulk_insert()
...
```

My questions are:
1. If I do not remap the old data(ex: log-20190804), so the timestamp will have two mappings (data vs data_nano), will there be a conflict when I use Kibana to search for the logs?
2. I didn't see many posts about using this new feature, will that hurt performance a lot? Did anyone use this in prod?
3. [Kibana not support nanoseconds search before 7.3](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32601) not sure if can sort by nanoseconds correctly, will try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: For `date_nanos` you need to create the mapping explicitly — otherwise the dynamic mapping will fall back to `date`.

And you are also correct that Kibana supports `date_nanos` in general in 7.3; though the relevant ticket is IMO https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/31424.

However, sorting doesn't work correctly yet. That is because both `date` (millisecond precision) and `date_nanos` (nanosecond precision) are represented as a long since the start of the epoche. So the first one will have a value of 1546344630124 and the second one of 1546344630123456789 — this isn't giving you the expected sort order.

In Elasticsearch there is a [parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#_sorting_numeric_fields) for search `"numeric_type": "date_nanos"` that will cast both to nanosecond precision and thus order correctly (added in 7.2). However, that parameter isn't yet used in Kibana. I've [raised an issue for that now](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/43939).

For performance: The [release blog post has some details](https://www.elastic.co/blog/journey-support-nanosecond-timestamps-elasticsearch). Obviously there is overhead (including document size), so I would only use the higher precision if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting question. I‘ve now turned it into a blog post with some additional information around it, since I can see the question come up again: https://xeraa.net/blog/2019_date-nano-elasticsearch-kibana/